# How to use default logging configuration of wildfly12(standalone\configuration\logging.properties) instead log4j2.properties?

Tags: java, struts2, log4j, log4j2, wildfly-12

I have migrated Struts2.3 version to Struts2.5 and updated log4j jar to log4j2.10 as it is used by Struts2.5 version. I am using default wildfly logging configuration(wildfly-12.0.0.Final\standalone\configuration\logging.properties). I am not using log4j2 in my project pragmatically. I have to include log4j2 and log4j-core jars only because struts2.5 version forcing to include.I do not want to use log4j2.properties file in my class path. I want to use default logging.properties but when i start servet it shows an error message -

(ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) ERROR StatusLogger No Log4j 2 configuration file found. Using default configuration (logging only errors to the console), or user programmatically provided configurations. Set system property 'log4j2.debug' to show Log4j 2 internal initialization logging. See https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html for instructions on how to configure Log4j 2

How to exclude this error message to be displayed on console or What can i change in any configuration file?

Answer (score 0):

This unfortunately isn't currently supported. There is however, a very old now :(, [JIRA](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFCORE-482) to add this support. I've updated the priority on this as it really does need to be done.

A less than ideal workaround would be to build [`log4j2-jboss-logmanager`](https://github.com/jboss-logging/log4j2-jboss-logmanager). If you would like to give it a try and would rather not build the project I could do an alpha release at any time.